# Closed form for convolutions of random variables

Tags: distributions

Is it possible to get Mathematica (9) to calculate PDF's for combined distributions? I can't seem to find the right notation, if this is possible at all. My attempts:

```
PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1] + NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
```

Nor can we store a distribution to a variable:

```
z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]
PDF[z, x]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[u + v, 
 {u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], 
  v \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2]}];
PDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

Note: check the correct syntax for [PDF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PDF.html) in the docs.

Comment: @Matt, my pleasure. Welcome to _Mathematica.SE_.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I do most of my coding in R, working on a review of Mathematica for R users right now...

Comment: @MattAsher I suppose you're aware of Mathematica 9's new [RLink feature](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/guide/RLink.html), right?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Yes I am. I'll be evaluating some of RLink's capabilities in my review.